# What are these instructions in Chat GPT model_comparisons.json

Tags: chatgpt-3.5

In my free ChatGPT 3.5 account I requested my data, it was sent to me the next day in a zip folder, one of the files is called model_comparisons.json.

I cant paste the whole file since it has lots of my personal info like userid and one of my past questions I asked ChatGPT, but one section piqued my interest.

`` {"content_type": "system_content", "model_identity_desc": "You are ChatGPT, a large language model trained by OpenAI, based on the GPT-3.5 architecture.", "instructions": null, "conversation_start_date": "2024-01-19T11:36:52.738892", "deprecated_knowledge_cutoff": "2022-01-01", "tools_section": {"guardian_tool": "Use the guardian tool to lookup content policy if the conversation falls under one of the following categories:\n - 'election_voting': Asking for election-related voter facts and procedures happening within the U.S. (e.g., ballots dates, registration, early voting, mail-in voting, polling places, qualification);\n\nDo so by addressing your message to guardian_tool using the following function and choose `category` from the list ['election_voting']:\n\nget_policy(category: str) -> str\n\nThe guardian tool should be triggered before other tools. DO NOT explain yourself."}, "content_policy": null, "output_config": null}, "status": "finished_successfully", "end_turn": true, "weight": 0.0, "recipient": "all"} ``

I am curious what the tools_section is and specifically the "guardian_tool", I asked ChatGPT about it and it denied any knowledge of it.

1. Does anyone know what the purpose of this model_comparisons.json is?
2. Has anyone else requested their data and see this?
3. Are there any other "tools" that ChatGPT uses?
4. Does anyone understand that the guardian tool is doing? To me it looks to me like any election related chats are reported to it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be referencing to a new tool the have for the 2024 worldwide elections
https://www.reddit.com/r/ChatGPT/comments/196k679/chatgpt_has_a_new_guardian_tool/

Comment: Please put some more details here.  Answers consisting only of links are not particularly useful and are liable to be deleted.